# Concat DataFrames without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ive got a problem with the DataFrames in Pandas/Python.
Lets say I have two DataFrames with different headers in the shape [2,10].
All I wanna do is to concat these two Frames to a new one with the shape [2,20]. So i want to "put them just behind each other". What python is doing is to make me a [3,20] shape with half of it beeing NaNs which i wanna avoid. Is there any solution to this?

The next question would be how to merge a new dataframe with the top one without getting NaNs again. So if I want to "put a new row under my top dataframe" to get a [3,20] shape, how can I achieve this? The header will be already present in the top [2,20] df.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add your table, and write your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`I guess you are looking for `pd.concat` using the `axis` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# dfo = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=[10, 2]), columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=[10, 2]), columns=['a', 'b'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
print(df)
```

That would return

```
    a   b
0  24  57
1  89  70
2  78  49
3  33  63
4  27   7
5  56  73
6  30  94
7  85  38
8  44  86
9  83  36
0  40  50
1  16  14
2   2  26
3  48  97
4  80  72
5  69  43
6  13  26
7  50   7
8  84  13
9  34  77
```

You can add a `reset_index()` at the end if you want to re-index `df`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

     0   1
0    0  91
1   86  21
2   48  76
3   98  61
4   28  18
5   38  44
6   67  31
7   27  17
8    4  63
9   48  16
10  95  26
11   2  61
12  23  67
13   4  74
14  82  47
15  64   6
16  66  60
17   3  47
18  14  98
19  16  71
```

If by "behind each other" you mean side-by-side, you just need to change the `axis=0` to `axis=1`.

However, I am not sure what you mean by avoiding NaNs.